# Angular2 POST data from Select Option

Tags: angular

I want to POST data to my API from value that i got from selected option. But i got `undefined` value.

This is my model:-

```
export class Process {
    id: number;
    class_id: string;
    notes: string;
    levelling_route: string;
    code: string;
  }
```

this is my post function

```
PostData(process: Process) {
        this.jobService.PostLevelling(process).subscribe(
          data=> this.event = JSON.stringify(data),
          error=> alert(error),
          () => console.log("Successful Post Data")
        )

        }
```

And my html

```
<select  class="form-control" id="select" name="code" size="1">
<option *ngFor="let obj of code" [(ngModel)]="code" name="code" [ngValue]={{obj?.id}} ngDefaultControl>{{obj?.name}}</option>
</select>
```

What did i miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this one..i got your issue

```
<select  class="form-control" id="select" name="code" size="1">

<option *ngFor="let obj of code" [(ngModel)]="code" name="code" 

 [ngValue]="obj.id" 

  ngDefaultControl>{{obj?.name}}</option>

</select>
```

or Use this way

```
<option *ngFor="let obj of code" [(ngModel)]="code" name="code" 

 value="{{obj.id}}" 

  ngDefaultControl>{{obj?.name}}</option>

</select>
```

Comment: i'd try the second way.. No error.. but when i try to `console log` the data that i `POST`.. i got undefined..

my console log

`console.log(process.code)`
`console.log(process.notes)`

Comment: first use inspect element on this controll and show the value of it,than check name of that field in a class ..may be u get actual solution..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the place, where you bind to your model. Move `[(ngModel)]="code"` up to your `<select>` tag.

Take a look at [the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html).

Comment: `Error trying to diff '2'`

Comment: Are you using the final version of Angular? I think you need to use `[value]="obj.id"`

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be something like this

```
<select class="form-control" id="select" name="code" [(ngModel)]="code" size="1">
    <option *ngFor="let obj of code" [value]="obj?.id">{{obj?.name}}</option>
</select>
```